# Can't get one thing to appear on another page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having a problem because when I write the code to display the "logs" on my users profiles pages it displays the html or the console information instead of the proper front end display with the image, and bootstrap customization.

here is what is displayed when I run my app:

> Log id: 1, description: "einstein", created_at: "2013-11-26 06:09:06",
>   updated_at: "2013-11-26 06:09:06", user_id: 1, image_file_name:
>   "93434191-einstein-tongue_custom-36fb0ce35776dc2d92e...",
>   image_content_type: "image/jpeg", image_file_size: 52317,
>   image_updated_at: "2013-11-26 06:09:03"

Here is the code I wrote in the profiles/show page:

```
<%= @user.username%>

<% @logs.each do |log| %> <%= log.inspect %> <% end %>
```

I believe I should be using the log.content command but doesn't work for me.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

`#inspect` is a debugging method in Ruby that, by default, prints a String showing its receiver's internal state. It's really helpful if you want to investigate what's being assigned where at some point in your application, but it has no "magic" to generate nice HTML, so it probably isn't what you want here.

If you want to render the images and other information, you'll have to do it by hand. Here's something that should get you started:

```
<ul class="logs">
<% @logs.each do |log| %>
  <li><%= image_tag(log.image_file_name, :alt => log.description) %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

You'll need to provide the rest of the actual image path, though, which depends on where you're putting the images when they're being uploaded.